# How to remove comma characters from a semicolon delimited List<string>?

Tags: c#, linq, list, character, delimiter

I've created a List of emails which is separated by semicolons in order to be processed safely.

But looking at the logs there was a case where the user input a comma "," character after each email, which caused a `An invalid character was found in the mail header: ','` error.

I did look at other answers out there on removing characters from a List and tried the below using Linq:

```
//Remove any invalid commas from the recipients list
recipients = string.Join(" ", recipients .Split().Where(w => !recipients.Contains(",")));
```

But the compiler tells me that `List<string>` does not contain a definition for `.Split()` doesn't exist in the current context. It's important that the processed List remains delimited by a ";" semicolon after the commas are removed.

**Question:**

How can I remove comma characters from a semicolon delimited List ?

**Code:**

```
List<string> recipients = new List<string>();

//Split the additional email string to List<string> 
// (check that the string isn't empty before splitting)
if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(adContacts.AdditionalEmails) != true)
{ recipients = adContacts.AdditionalEmails.Split(';').ToList(); }


//Remove any invalid commas from the recipients list
recipients = string.Join(" ", text.Split().Where(w => !recipients.Contains(",")));
```

Comment: `text = text.Replace(",", "");`? To remove all the commas?

Comment: Surely you just replace commas with semi colons? or am I missing the point

Comment: Looking back on the code, my adContacts.AdditionalEmails string is already delimited by semicolons, so I just needed to remove the commas: `adContacts.AdditionalEmails.Replace(",", ""); recipients = adContacts.AdditionalEmails.Split(';').ToList();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on what do you mean by *delete all commas*. To *delete* commas within the entire `text`:

```
text = text.Replace(",", "");
```

In your case it will be

```
 recipients = adContacts.AdditionalEmails
   .Replace(",", "")
   .Split(';')
   .ToList(); // <- do you really want to convert array into a list?
```

To *convert* commans into semicolons

```
text = text.Replace(',', ';');
```

To *remove all the eMails* that contain comma:

```
recipients = string.Join(";", text
  .Split(';')
  .Where(w => !w.Contains(",")));
```

Finally, you can *treat* comma as a *valid separator* as well as semicolon:

```
var eMails = text.Split(new char[] {';', ','}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Comment: I actually should have removed from the adContacts.AdditionalEmails string instead. So the following worked in my case: `adContacts.AdditionalEmails.Replace(",", "");
                    recipients = adContacts.AdditionalEmails.Split(';').ToList();`

First remove any commas, then split by the semicolon delimiter already present in the string.

Comment: @Brian J: please notice, that `Remove` *doesn't change* the string, but returns a *new one* (so `adContacts.AdditionalEmails.Replace(",", "");` will create a new string and then drops is). `recipients = adContacts.AdditionalEmails.Replace(",", "").Split(';').ToList();`

Answer (score 0):

The compiler error is because recipients is a List not a string, and List's don't have a Split method.

So use the List.RemoveAll method:

```
// Remove any invalid commas from the recipients list.
recipients = string.Join(" ", recipients.RemoveAll(item => item.Contains(",")));
```

Comment: I'd bet, that OP wants to *replace* commas to semicolons instead of *remove*.

Answer (score 0):

you may want to replace all commas with semicolon:

```
recipients=recipients.Replace(",",";");
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this approach:

```
List<string> newRecipients = recipients
   .Select(r => String.Join(";", r.Split(',', ';')))
   .ToList();
```

This will split every recipient by the possible comma and semicolon delimiters. Then it will build new recipients by joining them with the correct semicolon.

Answer (score 0):

I'd split with a regex:

```
Regex.Split(input, @"[\,\;]+").Where(s => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s))
```